# How can I search for documents in Unity?

Tags: unity, search

I would like to hit the super key, start typing a document name and have that document just show up.  It seems like this is something Unity should do. Am I mistaken or have I somehow corrupted something?

Comment: When 12.04 comes out we might get something called a Heads Up Display. Have a look - http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dash files lens will only return results for files that have been **previously** opened. As far as folders it will only return those that contain at least one **previously** opened file

If desired you can still use the old gnome search tool, look in /usr/share/applications for it, (Search for Files) & if desired add to launcher or add thru a launcher icon quicklist

Answer (score 1):

Looks like by default unity only returns searches for recently opened files and folders.  This is pretty archaic considering real-time queries have been done on operating systems dating back decades.  I guess the man power and/or OS power is just not up to par for real time queries.

Answer (score 0):

The super key will pull up the dash, then click on the find files section, then start typing in your file, it will find all files.  I have not tried to just search generic and see if it would find a file that way or not.  I know it finds applications, I usually use the main search function to find programs, not files.  I hope this helps you out.